# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation Installation Error Prerequisites

Tags: installation

Receiving the following error on installation of Sharepoint:
[image]

What action should I take please?

The server is updated with latest windows updates and I have restarted a number of times.

Thank you,

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be a known issue:

ISSUE #3:  in http://www.linkedin.com/groups/COMMON-MICROSOFT-SHAREPOINT-INSTALLATION-ISSUES-3837859.S.49902410

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are experiencing a common issue, caused by orphaned registry keys.

The following was taken from a [social.technet question reply](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/bccdb9f1-dd91-4db1-bd19-6bfa658727f5/) from Bill Baer.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile - if the value of the UpdateExeVolatile registry key is anything other than 0 you will see this message.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations - if the PendingFileRenameOperations registry key has any value you will see this message.
>
> See additional information below:
>
> To remove an orphaned UpdateExeVolatile registry key value:
>
> 1. Open a registry editor, such as Regedit.exe or Regedt32.exe.
> 2. Navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\
> 3. In the right navigation pane, double-click the UpdateExeVolatile key.
> 4. Configure the key with a value of 0
> 5. Close Registry Editor.
>
> To delete the orphaned PendingFileRenameOperations registry key :
>
> 1. Open a registry editor, such as Regedit.exe or Regedt32.exe.
> 2. Navigate to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\
> 3. In the right navigation pane, right-click the PendingFileRenameOperations key and select Delete.
> 4. Close Registry Editor.

**I would add: please exercise extreme caution while editing the registry**. You never know WHY the keys where wrong in the first place and if the issue accually hides a malfunctioning somewhere else...